# Where is the link to the RSS feed?

Tags: support, rss

I just would add the feed of newest questions to my reader, but I did not found it. It works with https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=usage&sort=newest.

Am I blind?

Answer (score 1):

I use https://german.stackexchange.com/feeds. Is this what you want?